VK-API: how do I change the "access_key" for a video file?
I need to restrict access to videos in VK.
Access to the file via a direct-linl in VK is prohibited (only VK-player widget).
I want to make access "privacy_view='by_link'" and change the "access_key" every night.
Is it possible?
Thanks
